# MVC C#.Net with JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am beginner of `JSON`. My confusion is why we are going with `JSON` instead of fetching and displaying data from back end with out using `Java Script/JQuery` in `MVC`.

I hope your answer will make me out from the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that everyone is going after JSON. But there are awful lot of them. There are 2 ways of rendering views in mvc, one is model binding, other is consuming api and rendering the elements through Javascript. The former involves usage of server resources for everything, while in latter, you just do db operation through server. Rendering of elements is done on client's machine. Thus it may give better performance and minimize server usage. But this improved performance comes at some cost.

Search engines like google discourage the second approach as its difficult for them to render complete view. Also Ajax only websites don't give good User Experience. And with increasing performance of technology stacks and servers, the performance is no longer a critical issue.

Other factors are security. Your security can be compromised if you are processing api data to render elements as malicious users can change the code and view what was not meant for them.

But if you don't care about SEO and implement your Ajax carefully, there is no harm in going second way also.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachit your answer made me to under stand a lot.

Comment: My pleasure. Accept it as the answer if it solved your query. For that you have tick the grey tick mark adjacent to the answer.

Comment: Dear Rachit,One quick question is there way to use AJAX updatepanel in MVC to consume our postback or we have to go with JSON?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying. Json is a datatype sent through web api, while ajax is the method of calling api through javascript.

Comment: Sorry Rachit, My question is whether we can able to use AJAX upatedpanel in MVC or not? that is my question. can u clear me please on this.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have knowledge on this

Answer (score 0):

JSON is great at modeling objects in string. This allows you to easily represent strongly typed objects and pass them over HTTP via POST data.

Lets say in C# you have a Job controller.

It has a method called

```
void Create(Job job)
{
    db.Jobs.Add(job);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the Job poco class looks like this.

```
public class Job
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public bool IsActive {get;set;}

}
```

You can write values to this or any object in JSON quite easily.
In your javascript you can set the values as a variable

```
var job = { 
   id: 23,
   name: 'Programming Job',
   isActive: true
};
```

You can convert this to string to prep for an ajax post like this.

```
var postData = JSON.stringify(job);
```

When you POST to your controller the JSON will automatically map to your C# Job class even with the different casings.

Allowing you to execute

> void Create(Job job)

Comment: Thanks a lot Proximo. Its a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is much faster and simpler to traval between backend and frontend.

The backend just deal with fetching data from the database. The client then deal with the display of that data.

Say you call a friend to get some help to make a cake. You have the ingredients, but have no idea how to make it.
Would you rather like your friend to ask you to come by his place so he can help you make the cake, or would you rather like him to give you the directions to make it yourself right then over the phone?

I'm not sure if my example is fully accurate :p

Comment: Hi Dear, Thanks for your reply but i am quite confuse with your answer.My confusion is which is the better way to get data from controller whether using JSON or using model binding instead of JSON and why?

Comment: @user2738864 oh, sorry. Well I'm not that skilled yet. The startup I'm working at uses both of these and I'm not sure which is better. I think it depends on how your project is build, and what are your needs.

Comment: Okay dear no worries :)